VS Code not jumping to the top stack frame
I'm trying to debug some Django library code with the default VS Code Python and Django debugging settings (and "justMyCode" = False). I've set a breakpoint in one of the library functions:

I call this from some user code, eg. formset.save(). When I debug and hit the breakpoint, VS Code jumps to this user code instead of the library code as I'd have expected:

Pressing "Step Into" seems to progress the library code, but keeps jumping back to the user code which is calling it.
The call stack seems to know about the library code, although it is greyed out:

If I click on save then the currently executing statement is highlighted:

I can go through the tedious process of stepping through, clicking the top stack frame, and then doing usual things like inspecting locals. The issue just seems to be about where VS Code is jumping to every time the debugger breaks (or maybe where pdb is telling VS Code to jump -- I'm not sure).
I want the library code which is currently being executed to be jumped to, and that's what I would have expected to happen.

Please post the code as text, not a screenshot.

The code isn't important -- it's the VS Code context.

Same problem here...
Any updates?

I see the same thing. Looks like a recent bug in VSCode. I rolled back to VSCode version 1.89 and it worked as expected.
This was fixed in version 1.90.1 (list of addressed issues).

upstream issue: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/215403

Yes, seems to be a feature not a bug: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/214433#issuecomment-2161360041

Fixed in 1.90.1:
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues?q=is%3Aissue+milestone%3A%22May+2024+Recovery+1%22+is%3Aclosed

for debugging the problem that you can't get into the library code could be due to the just my code setting. Click on File and select Preferences and go to Settings. Search for the justMyCode setting and change this setting to false.

